# How to make a constructor similar to multidimensional vectors?

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++17

For a `vector` type, we can do this:

```
vector<vector<int>> v = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

I'm trying to do the same for a custom class `SomeClass`, so that I can do:

```
SomeClass a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

How do I write the constructor for `SomeClass` to achieve this?

Comment: depends on the `SomeClass` constructor

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you refer me to one possible way of doing this? Based on that, I'm sure I could figure out the rest based on the design of `SomeClass`.

Comment: the `{1,2,3}` is just a constructor that accept a `std::initializer_list`, in case of `std::vector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `std::initializer_list` for which you can find a good [documentation here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

If you define your `SomeClass` as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        SomeClass(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> param)
        {
            //...
        }
};
```

Then you will be able to construct an instance of this class the way you wanted it:

```
SomeClass a {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

*You can find [here a small example](https://godbolt.org/z/3x3jvv).*